# How to include image(.png) in legend of an excel chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, images, charts

All,

I am trying to include company logos as legends of excel charts instead of their names automatically using VBA. Any leads will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is this can't be done-[even with VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840546(v=office.14).aspx) (tl;dr legends can only be formatted text-no images or fills).  But as with most things Excel, you can fake it pretty easily.

1. Create your chart and format your symbols.
2. In column of cells, enter your symbols (consider using a wing-ding type font to match as closely as possible).
3. Paste your logos and format the size to match your row height (I find .25" works pretty well).
4. Place the logo images to the right of your symbols in the cells.
5. Turn off all grid lines (helps make a polished look).
6. Use Excel's Camera Tool (may have to activate it on your ribbon), to make an image of your symbol/logo cells.
7. Past the image onto your chart and organize/format to taste.

Here's a sample:

[image: Logo Legends]